# execution order with jQuery's AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code (ajax is async):

```
function echoHello()
{
    return "hello";
}

function echoWorld()
{
    return $.ajax({
        //this will return "world";
    });
}

console.log(echoHello());

$.when(echoWorld()).done(function(response)
{
    console.log(response);
});
```

which outputs "**hello**" and "**world**" (in that order). But if change it a little bit, so the `console.log()` is in different order:

```
function echoHello()
{
    return "hello";
}

function echoWorld()
{
    return $.ajax({
        //this will return "world";
    });
}

$.when(echoWorld()).done(function(response)
{
    console.log(response);
});

console.log(echoHello());
```

is the same output guaranteed? Or it could potentially output "**world**" and then "**hello**"?

Comment: guaranteed - synchronous code always completes before asynchonous code can start

Comment: https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-the-event-loop-74cd408419ff#:~:text=JavaScript%20is%20a%20single%2Dthreaded,can%20happen%20at%20a%20time.&text=That's%20where%20asynchronous%20JavaScript%20comes,without%20blocking%20the%20main%20thread. is  very useful in understanding how this all works.

Comment: Depends if what's hidden by the comments can change: https://jsfiddle.net/e6wvqb1p/ But if you are sure `echoWorld` is async, then yes, the order here is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.ajax() returns a [jqXHR](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) Object which implements the Promise interface. And if [async](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) option is false, it sends a **Synchronous** Ajax Request and returns a **resolved** Promise.

And for the [$.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) if the argument is neither Deferred nor Promise nor Thenable, it returns a **resolved** Promise.

So below example will print "Sync", "Hello", "World", "Async".

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3af2m7z8/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    let echoHello = () => "Hello";
    let echoAsync = () => $.ajax({url: "data:text,Async"});
    let echoSync = () => $.ajax({ async: false, url: "data:text,Sync" });

    let log = response => console.log(response);

    $.when(echoAsync()).done(log); // logs "Async"
    $.when(echoSync()).done(log); // logs "Sync"
    $.when(echoHello()).done(log); // logs "Hello"
    console.log('World'); // logs "World"
});
```

And, for your information, as of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax makes a call to the web server and is asynchronous. You don't know how long it will take. It is the same as

```js
setTimeout(_ => { console.log('world'); }, 0);
console.log('Hello');
```

Hello will run first as the async function runs after the current block even though the time is set to 0.